# how to change the result of this get function into two lines down?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, web-services, restful-url

```js
function getotherResource(){
        $result = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/otherResource'));
        $html = "";
        foreach($result as $r){
        $html.="<div class='m-b-xs m-t'>
        <label class='i-checks i-checks-md'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='chkotherResource' id='v-".$r->qEmployee."' value='".$r->employeeName."'>
            <i></i>
            ".$r->employeeName."
          </label>
        </div>";
        }
        echo $html;
    }
```

[this my display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3Nv.png)
[how to change the look like this with the array?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqsQ5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would use css to solve for this, specifically the new grid spec. I would wrap the foreach in another div.wrapper:

```
function getotherResource(){
        $result = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->API.'/otherResource'));
        $html = "***<div class='wrapper'>***";
        foreach($result as $r){
        $html.="<div class='m-b-xs m-t'>
        <label class='i-checks i-checks-md'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='chkotherResource' id='v-".$r->qEmployee."' value='".$r->employeeName."'>
            <i></i>
            ".$r->employeeName."
          </label>
        </div>";
        }
        ***$html.="</div>"***
        echo $html;
    }
```

And add the following css.

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
}
```

Comment: I've tried and that's not what I want but thanks a lot for his advice.

Comment: What about it is not what you are looking for?  If it't not ordering right I think there are other css that can be added to order it how you would like. However if it is not the solution could you provide some clarification?

Comment: sorry, i have 2 image in my post you can see that .
image 1 is display from my syntax,and i want to change image 2?
if i use your css my display not divided into 2 columns only 1 column down and looks smaller.